# org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath does not affect used browser

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, xulrunner

Eclipse by default uses IE on windows, I need to use firefox, but I can not configure eclipse to do that.

I downloaded xulrunner from http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/images/Xulrunner-31.0.en-US.win64-x86_64.zip, then set `org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath` in eclipse.ini:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=d:\xul\xulrunner
```

But eclipse still using IE as internal browser. There are no errors in error log.

What is wrong?

I use java: 1.7.0_67 x86_64, eclipse: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is quite easy. There were two problems:

- I missed property in eclipse.ini (`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`)
- I used incorrect xulrunner version (need to use `24.0`, downloaded from http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/images/Xulrunner-24.0.en-US.win64-x86_64.zip)

These steps are described in the faq: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla

Answer (score 2):

Setting 'org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath' just tells Eclipse where to find XULRunner, it does not tell Eclipse to use it.

Open Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser and choose the browser you want to use.

Comment: I can not set internal browser type there, just external type.